# jqgrid in celledit mode, modify not saved after click next page/prev page etc

Tags: jqgrid, save, blur

I've a grid using cell-edit mode. The problem is: after the last cell is modified, the focus is still in that cell.
Then, no ENTER/ESC is pressed, directly click the next page to do input for next page.  After some days, they find the last cell of each page is NOT saved as expected.

How to deal with this?

I've tried to modify jqgrid.src.js to bind('blur') on the cell-edit element to call the saveCell like this

```
....
$("input, select, textarea", cc).bind("keydown" .
....
//my code start here
.bind("blur", function (e) {
     $($t).jqGrid("saveCell", iRow, iCol);
)
//my code end here
```

This will save the modification as expected. BUT, the NEXT-PAGE/PRE-PAGE of the grid does not work anymore until a reload.

I think this is a common problem for jqgrid users.

Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use [onPaging](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager#events) callback as the place for saving the editing cell by `saveCell`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27297556/315935).

Comment: Oleg, you are the master of JQGRID. Thanks for your answer. I've tried your method. the same probem exists: save is done, after that,  PAGE BUTTON does not work. I'm using jqgrid 4.7.1.  My test grid has 2 pages. I modify a cell on page 1, than click NEXT PAGE, the cell is saved. paging does not work.

Comment: It seemed like the current page is ERROR after saveCell is called.

Comment: @user3754671: Try to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.1. It's the fork which I develop starring with making jqGrid commercial (see [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) and renaming jqGrid to Guriddo jqGrid JS (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)).

Comment: I've tried to use free jqGrid 4.13.1 about ten days ago.  The showlink formatter seems does not work as the old version.  And, my code used showlink a lot. And then for stability, I rollback to 4.7.1 again.  I'll try free-jqGrid for this ISSUE later. maybe 1-2 days later. Thanks.

Comment: my showlink like this  formatter: 'showlink'
                  , formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:', showAction: "GetAndShowOrderData(jQuery('#preorderlst_d'),'#preorder_detail_wrapper','/Order/DetailsGS/','retID','", addParam: "','GG');" }      This works fine in 4.7.1. But in free jqGrid 4.13.1, the url of the link is generated with errors.

Comment: @user3754671: Sorry, but there are **no way back**. If you find some error (inclusive compatibility error) you should **report it**. I [updated](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/2494a5968476bc0d1729f8844a8cdc085487e282) the code of showlink now to support quotes. Try with the latest sources from GitHub. If you have some other problem (with `onPaging` for example) then you should create the demo and describe shortly the test case. Having it I can fix the problem (typically at the same day or more quickly).